# Como poner codigo encriptado %C3%B3 aplication.properties?

Tags: java, sql, json, spring, url

Me encuentro utilizando Java con el framework Spring. Sabiendo esto, me pidieron en mi trabajo que mi url se vea de esta manera:
https://instituto.ipp.cl/amigo-referido-admisi%C3%B3n?token_referido=4968a34d-d2f0-4f83-ae34-a5a9d2b2edc7
Lo cual por el momento no le estaria encontrando una solucion, ya que es la primera vez que hago este tipo de cambios.
Mi url actualmente se encuentra asi:
https://instituto.ipp.cl/amigo-referido-admisi%C3%83%C2%B3n?token_referido=4968a34d-d2f0-4f83-ae34-a5a9d2b2edc7
Sabrian posibles soluciones? Sera un problema sencillo? Agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso estas confundiendo `encriptar` con `codificar`, en tú caso lo que tienes es una URL codificada porque esta utilizando un carácter con acento, la URL seria equivalente a `https://instituto.ipp.cl/amigo-referido-admisión` ahora aquí en tramos a un dilema entre lo correcto y lo que se puede o no hacer. Segun la especificación [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) dice que la URL se conforma de una seria de caracteres limitados y en caso de caracteres no especificados se deben mapear al equivalente `US-ASCII` para mantener legible la URL y no colocar `%C3%B3` como equivalente esto solo para las partes que componen la URL más no sus valores.

El problema que tienes es que no estas siguiendo el estándar y por eso te encuentras con casos extraños, porque lo que te piden es que la URL contenga `%C3%B3` que equivale a `ó` pero en tu URL tienes `%C3%83%C2%B3` que equivale a `Ã³` que es como un carácter no reconocido, esto se puede deber a que estas desplegando el aplicativo en ambiente con el sistema operativo Linux en ingles y Java tomara el el set de caracteres del sistema operativo el cual no contiene acentos, lo que debes de hacer es cambiar el set de caracteres por defecto del sistema operativo y verificar que tu servicio se vea de esta forma:

```
@PostMapping("/amigo-referido-admisión")
public String servicio(@RequestParam("token_referido") String token){
    return "Amigo " + token;
}
```

Pero yo te recomiendo que la solución sea cambiar a la `o` sin acento.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tanto para corregirme en mi pronunciacion como con mi problema! Me sirvio y comente a mi grupo que la mejor solucion era la o sin acento.

Comment: Que bueno que haya sido de ayuda mi respuesta, ten en cuenta que este estándar es el mismo que se aplica a las URLs de los sitios web, por eso no se utilizan caracteres con acento pero como todo queda a vuestro criterio si se aplica o no.